# system verilog /oop

Tags: oop, system-verilog

The object in the below code has been instantiated just once, right?  So the single object that has been instantiated should contain a single integer i field whose value is 2.  Why does `p.i` give 1 instead of 2?  Is this specific to SystemVerilog?  Or do all oop languages behave similarly?

```
class Packet; 
  integer i = 1;
  function integer get();
    get = i;
  endfunction 
endclass

class LinkedPacket extends Packet;
  integer i = 2;
  function integer get();
    get = -i;
  endfunction 
endclass

LinkedPacket lp = new;
Packet p = lp;
j = p.i; // j = 1, not 2
j = p.get(); // j = 1, not -1 or –2
```

Thanks

Comment: Having those semicolons at the end of the first line of multiline class/function definitions seems like it'd be pretty confusing, considering that the semicolons are used elsewhere to indicate end-of-statement. Does SystemVerilog require that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is pasted from section 8.13 of the the 1800-2009 SystemVerilog specification, which explains the issue.  My opinion is that overriding class members like this is a really bad idea.  The example in the specification is simply there to illustrate how it works.

The class property `integer i` is defined in both the base class and child class.  This declaration in `LinkedPacket` overrides and hides the declaration in `Packet`.

From the specification:

> In this case, references to p access the methods and class properties of the Packet class. So, for example, if
>   class properties and methods in LinkedPacket are overridden, these overridden members referred to
>   through p get the original members in the Packet class. From p, new and all overridden members in
>   LinkedPacket are now hidden.

Since you are calling the function through a handle to `Packet` you get the values from `Packet`.

In addition, the `get()` function is not declared `virtual`.  This is why you do not see the integer being negated.  This is also noted in the example in the specification.

> To call the overridden method via a base class object (p in the example), the method needs to be declared
>   virtual (see 8.19).

This behavior is not unique to SystemVerilog and is similar to what you would observe in other OO languages.

If you want to have a different value for `i` in `LinkedPacket`, the proper way to do this would be to only declare `i` in the base class, and initialize it differently in the constructor.

e.g.

```
class Packet; 

  integer i;

  function new();
    i = 1;
  endfunction

  virtual function integer get();
    get = i;
  endfunction 

endclass

class LinkedPacket extends Packet;

  function new();
    i = 2;
  endfunction

  virtual function integer get();
    get = -i;
  endfunction 

endclass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no SystemVerilog expert, but I'd expect `p.i` to return `1` as that is what you initialise it to.  `p.get()` is just another way to return the same value, so that will also be `1`.

`j=get();` will (I think) return `-2` - without an object prefix, I'd expect it to call the second function which is outside of the class.